# Block feed importer to create a new term in taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds, importing-exporting

I am using feed importer to bulk import the nodes in a drupal site. I have created a custom content type named Product. This content type has CCK fields which are linked with a taxonomy.

I am using CSV files to import the data. If I put a different(invalid) value in one of the field and that is not present in the vocabulary(term in the taxonomy), it creates a new term.

I want to block the creation of the new taxonomy term as it might create some invalid term in my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it using [Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper). We can control the fields that we want to import.